# Can't properly use python stockfish package in Mac

Tags: engines, stockfish, python

I'm trying to get stockfish for python working but I am running into issues. This is my code so far.

```
from stockfish import Stockfish
stockfish = Stockfish('/Users/Me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stockfish/models.py')
```

This returns a `OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/Users/Me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stockfish/models.py'`

This is where I downloaded the package from: https://pypi.org/project/stockfish/. After this, as I have a Mac, I downloaded it through homebrew and my installation has a path `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/stockfish/15`, but this also does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download an appropriate stockfish binary at https://stockfishchess.org/download/.

Remember where it is and use that location and engine filename.

```
stockfish = Stockfish('/engine_path/engine_filename')
```

Comment: I realized my mistake. The file was inside `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/stockfish/15` but I had to do  `⌘+Shift+G` in order to actually find the stockfish file inside. The final path ended up being `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/stockfish/15/bin/stockfish`

Comment: Thanks I was doing the exact same thing @Ozzy08. This helped alot

Answer (score 2):

I think the path that you give to the Stockfish constructor is wrong.

According to this page https://pypi.org/project/stockfish/ you should rather give the path to where you installed your engine, so probably `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/stockfish/15` , not some python file in the stockfish package.